# Laravel - move index.php file in project/public

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5.1

I am hosting my Laravel project on shared hosting where I don't have access to modify the apache config to look for the `index` file in `/public`.

I've also tried adding `DirectoryIndex index.html` to my `.htaccess` file at the place where the hosting is looking for the `index.php` file.

This does not work.

That being said, I think I can solve the problem if I simply move the `index.php` file out of `/public` (where Laravel has it by default) to the `root` where the hosting is looking for it.

That being said, what do I need to modify in this `index.php` file to allow the Laravel app to work?

My structure is:

```
public_html/ <-- where my files are served from and where index.php should be 
    my-project/
           public/
               index.php <-- where Laravel expects index.php to be to bootstrap the app
```

Comment: If you're hosting it to live then just point your domain to Laravel public folder, why do you need to move `index.php` outside of public?

Answer (score 2):

Okay here we go:

Let's say this is your folder structure:

```
MyUser/
   public_html/
       public/
```

### What you want to do is:

---

***Step 1.*** create a folder on the same level as `public_html` named `laravel` (or something to your liking):

```
MyUser/
   laravel/
   public_html/
       public/
```

---

***Step 2.*** upload ***ALL*** your laravel code to the `laravel` folder. Your code is now inaccessible through a web browser.

---

***Step 3.*** Next, you copy all data from `MyUser/Laravel/public` to `MyUser/public_html`. Now we're getting somewhere. ***Warning:*** *Don't forget to copy the `.htaccess` file too*

---

***Step 4.*** open `MyUser/public_html/index.php` in your favorite editor and change

`$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`

to:

`$app = require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';`

and change:

`require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php'`

to:

`require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php'`

---

***Step 5.*** Now, since your `storage` directory is outside of your `public_html`, it'll most likely not be accessible, so `CHMOD` that to 777, and you're done!

---

A small tip:

See if you can create a `symlink` from `MyUser/laravel/public` to `MyUser/public_html`. That'll let you skip step 3 and 4.

Hope this helped.